# Datatype of object used to set position in file in C++?

Tags: c++, file

In the following piece of code:

```
myFile.seekg(6, ios::beg);
```

I read that ios::beg is an object of the class ios_base::seekdir - what is 'seekdir' - as ios_base is a class, how can we use the scope resolution operator on it?
Also, sometimes we use ios::beg, and sometimes ios_base::beg, which is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::ios_base` is a class where `seekdir` is a member type (which happens to be an enum). `ios::beg` works as well as `ios_base::beg` because `ios` inherits from `ios_base` publicly. Source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios